# Registrar dos formularios en Mysql con tabla referenciada

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de ingresar los datos de **dos formularios** con un solo boton, en donde una tabla esta referenciada con la otra.

Tabla perfil se referencia con usuarios. al momento del registro quiero que se ingresen en sus tablas respectivas `Tabla usuarios` y `Tabla perfil` obviando que la tabla perfil tiene la llave foranea que se referencia con la tabla usuarios.

El submit si lo hace, si guarda en la parte de usuarios pero al momento de revisar los datos de perfil, este no llena nada, tengo dos `action` para los dos formularios `reg_usuarios.php` y `reg_perfil.php`

**EJEMPLO**

> Tabla usuarios

idUsuario pk

email

pass

> Tabla perfil

id pk

nombre

apellido

idUsuarioPerfil fk

Como puedo inserter los datos al mismo tiempo pero referenciando que la informacion de perfil pertenece a su usuario?

**SOLUCION**
Con creditos a Matias Olivera

Esta solucion es con pdo ya que es lo que estoy utilizando, al final de la sentencia del primer insert se inserta un

```
$statement = conexion->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID");
$id = $statement->fetchColumn();
```

y listo!

Comment: Buenas, por favor revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: dejame ver si entendi, quieres hacer 2 insert?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo si, quiero inserter los datos del formulario usuarios en la table usuarios, y el formulario de perfil en la table de perfil referenciando que la informacion que se ingreso en perfil pertenece al usuario, con la referencia que es la llave foranea, no se si me dia a entender

Comment: La relación usuarios -> perfil es uno a uno, es decir, que como máximo un usuario va a tener un perfil. Este tipo de relaciones se pueden evitar, juntando las columnas de ambas tablas en una sola.

Comment: @MatiasOlivera si lo tenia de esa manera pero son dos tipos de clientes los que se registraran, y si hacia la base de datos de esa manera, se volvia muy confuse, es por ello que opte por hacerla de esta manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar el método `insert_id` *(Estilo orientado a objetos)* de `mysqli` para obtener el id autoincremental que se genera en el primer `insert` y pasarle como un argumento más al segundo `insert`.

```
<?php
/* Obtiene los datos del formulario */
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];

/* Crea una conexión con la base de datos*/
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db");

/* Chequea la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Error de conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Crea un nuevo usuario */
$consulta = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$consulta->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$consulta->execute();

/* Devuelve el id autoincremental que se utilizó en el insert */
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;

/* Crea un nuevo perfil */
$consulta = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO perfil (nombre, apellido, idUsuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$consulta->bind_param("ssi", $nombre, $apellido, $id);
$consulta->execute();

/* Cierra la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[Documentación: Insert_id](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: lo hice de la manera en que me indicaste, y al momento de darle submit, me indica que `undefined index nombre`

Comment: Los nombres (`name`) de los campos del formulario tienen que coincidir con las claves que le pasas a la variable superglobal `$_POST`.

Comment: y en efecto, si son los mismos

Comment: estoy usando PDO

Comment: en PDO:: lo solucione de la siguiente manera, lo ponder como solucion en el post